# Dynamically change button text when user enters contents into EditText

Tags: android, button, android-widget, textview

I have a TextView and Edittext and a button. On initialization, the button has a title, so I want to change the button text when the user starts typing on the EditText and when they delete the contents, the button text should be set back to the initial text.

So on the onCreate, I set the button text as follow : `button.setText("Touch me");`
 Then this:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText.getText()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(textView.getText())){
              button.setText("It's started");
}
```

The text gets changed when the app launches only but doesn't change when EditText is empty.

How can I change the text on the button dynamically?